# Spark dataframe: deleting an element from an array

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe with column1 as:

column1: WrappedArray( Book1/Title1, Book2/Title2, Book3/Title3)
column2:  This is first sentence

I want to remove the first element from both columns, the desired o/p for column1 and column2 respectively is:

column1: WrappedArray(Book2/Title2, Book3/Title3)
column2: is first sentence

For column2 here is the UDF that I wrote, but it is not working

```
val removefirst = udf((x: String) => x.split(" ").slice(1,x.split(" ").size).mkString(" "))
```

Any help with this will be great.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to map `tail` onto the `WrappedArray`.

Answer (score 0):

```
val removefirst = udf((x: String) => x.split(" ").slice(1,x.split(" ").size).mkString(" "))
```

The above code works fine for column2. Will post column 1 solution later.